# Laravel Spark is not displaying images that are stored in the /storage/app/public/profiles/ directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

The default for uploaded images appears to be /storage/app/public/profiles/, but the frontend generated URL of /storage/profiles/**image** isn't being found.

I tried to find any sort of routing for that directory and haven't been able to do so. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must link to the storage directory. From the [documentation](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/1.0/installation#linking-the-storage-directory):

> Once Spark is installed, you should link the public/storage directory to your storage/app/public directory. Otherwise, user profile photos stored on the local disk will not be available

And the relevant code:

```
ln -s /path/to/storage/app/public /path/to/public/storage
```

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I missed it. I used the Spark Installer directions and missed this section below.

Comment: @JohnFable no problem. We've all been there, many times! Glad it helped.

Comment: @camelCase I ran into same exact issue, though I knew it needs a symlink, I went ahead and created it but it still doesn't work for me. it's getting me 404 for routes like /storage/profiles/09c058b621dad442be436086449de1f1.jpeg

Comment: @AndrewMalinnkov mostly because u will need to call it by `storage/public/profiles/xxxxx.jpg`

Comment: @ctf0 no, not really, unfortunately :/ it still doesnt work

Comment: For those who interested I had to run the command `ln -sr storage/app/public public/storage` from within the Homestead Virtual Machine rather than host, which I did previously

Comment: any option for windows users instead of using " ln -s /path/to/storage/app/public /path/to/public/storage"?

Comment: As of Laravel 5.3 you can use the `php artisan storage:link` command

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the storage folder inside public folder and run the command using absolute paths(from root folder).