# Laravel Spark Symlink for Profile Pictures is not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-spark

I'm having some troubles with the symbolic linking of my storage directories in a fresh Spark installation. I checked the Spark docs ([found here](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/1.0/installation)), and I've tried to follow the instructions under the *Linking the Storage Directory* Section. But, when I run the command

`ln -s /storage/app/public /public/storage`

I get the following error:

`ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/public/storage’: No such file or directory`.

This is odd because I've checked via the command line and my editor, and the directory does exist.

I've also tried using

`ln -sr /storage/app/public /public/storage` as suggested [here](https://github.com/laravel/internals/issues/34).

This did create the symbolic link. But in my application, I still get 404 errors.

For some additional information that may help: I'm using a Homestead environment to develop and I set up my project with the Spark Installer. I also checked out this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847396/laravel-spark-is-not-displaying-images-that-are-stored-in-the-storage-app-publi) Stack Overflow Question, but it suggested that I take the same steps that I have already tried.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `ln -s $(pwd)/storage/app/public $(pwd)/public/storage` from your project directory (the directory that has `composer.json` in it). The command you're running tries to make a link from `/storage...` which is in the root of the filesystem. You *do* need to use an absolute path when running `ln`, but you need to use the full path to your project. For example, in Homestead my path is `/home/vagrant/project-name/storage/app/public`.

Comment: For those of you running spark on a cloud provider, you can add this to your composer.json [post-install-cmd](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#defining-scripts): `ln -sr storage/app/public public/storage`

Comment: If you are running Homestead, or another Vagrant-type Linux VM, as your development environment, you must create the symlink from inside your VM.